# How can I create all sums of combinations from a tuple? (interview)

Tags: python, tuples, combinations

I encounter a question on the interview and it was challenging. The topic was based in Decision analysis. The question is that Let's assume we have a tuple;

```
(15, 8, 8, 3)
```

And we want to create all sums of all combinations one by one without repeating and summing same numbers such as this output;

```
[(23, 8, 3), (18, 8, 8), (15, 11, 8)]
```

Another example;

```
(6, 5, 3, 8)
```

And output is:

```
[(11, 3, 8), (9, 5, 8), (14, 5, 3), (6, 8, 8), (6, 13, 3), (6, 5, 11)]
```

Note: Order is flexible.

I just really wonder the answer so if anyone is interested in this coding challenge, would help me to improve my mind structure.

Comment: Not sure if I'm following the "ordering" of the resulting sums here.  `(23, 8, 3)` implies you take 8 and 3 as single elements, but not 15.  Why is that?

Comment: Why no `(15, 16, 3)` in first output?

Comment: Is there a reason that every tuple of your result has length 3? Why is 16 and 31 not in the answer of your first example?

Comment: @BradSolomon, I think the resulting output is formed by taking unique combinations of only two elements from the parent tuple. For example, the first one can be thought of as `(15 + 8, 8, 3), (15 + 3, 8, 8) & (15, 8 + 3, 8)`... I also think `(15, 8 + 8, 3)` should be included as well

Comment: I actually do not know why, but 8+8 is not allowed. Also, same arrays or tuples such as [15, 11, 8], [15, 8, 11] not allowed as well. Only one of them can be considered.

Comment: @wim I think that's the "… and repeating same numbers" rule. For a real problem spec, this is way too vague, but for an interview question, that's probably intentional—they want you to notice the vagueness and ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In[2]: from itertools import combinations
  ...: 
  ...: 
  ...: def solution(nums):
  ...:     result = []
  ...:     seen = set()
  ...:     for p in combinations(range(len(nums)), r=2):
  ...:         dex_1, dex_2 = p
  ...:         if nums[dex_1] == nums[dex_2]:
  ...:             continue
  ...:         current = []
  ...:         for i, elem in enumerate(nums):
  ...:             if i == dex_1:
  ...:                 current.append(elem + nums[dex_2])
  ...:             elif i != dex_2:
  ...:                 current.append(elem)
  ...:         sorted_current = tuple(sorted(current))
  ...:         if sorted_current not in seen:
  ...:             result.append(tuple(current))
  ...:         seen.add(sorted_current)
  ...:     return result
  ...: 
In[3]: solution((15, 8, 8, 3))
Out[3]: [(23, 8, 3), (18, 8, 8), (15, 11, 8)]
In[4]: solution((6, 5, 3, 8))
Out[4]: [(11, 3, 8), (9, 5, 8), (14, 5, 3), (6, 8, 8), (6, 13, 3), (6, 5, 11)]
```

Comment: "And we want to create all sums of all combinations one by one without repeating"

Comment: Yes, (15, 16, 3)  is not allowed.

Comment: Also, [15, 11, 8] and [15, 8, 11] are same that is not allowed.

Comment: Yes, I tried that it works! Now, I try to understand how you did to improve myself!

Comment: I'm not sure that you missed things, so much as that the question was (probably intentionally) vague and you went with the most obvious interpretation before realizing it was a bit of a trick question. (Because outside of certain kinds of annoying interviews, you don't get trick questions like this.)

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Well, who doesn't still have a lot to learn? If you get to the point where you know everything you're ever going to know, it's time to retire. :)

Answer (score 5):

I think the best way to solve problems like this is to start with the slow, brute-force solution, because then you can visually see where the work is happening. Others disagree and prefer to think through the possible algorithms up-front, but this is my answer, so...

Start by ignoring the duplicate number rule, to make things simpler:

```
def sumcombos(tup):
    for i, x in enumerate(tup):
        for j, y in enumerate(tup[i+1:], i+1):
            yield tup[:i] + (x+y,) + tup[i+1:j] + tup[j+1:]
```

You should be able to understand how that works, right?

If you explicitly need a `list` of `tuple`s instead of any iterable, wrap it:

```
def sumcomboslist(lst):
    return list(sumcombos(lst))
```

Now, the problem is that this is going to output `(23, 8, 3)` twice, and it's also going to output `(15, 16, 3)`. The rule to avoid that is "without repeating and summing same numbers". Interpreting what that means isn't easy,<sup>*</sup> but once you do, implementing it is:

```
def sumcombos(lst):
    for i, x in enumerate(lst):
        if x in lst[:i]: continue
        for j, y in enumerate(lst[i+1:], i+1):
            if y in lst[:j]: continue
            yield tup[:i] + (x+y,) + tup[i+1:j] + tup[j+1:]
```

So, what's the performance? Well, the inner loop obviously runs `N**2` times, and we've got an `if y in lst[:j]` that takes linear time inside that loop, so it's `N**3`. Now, for our examples, where the largest `N` ever seen is 4, that's fine, but in most real-life situations, cubic algorithms are a problem.

If we can use linear space, we can improve that by building a dict up-front mapping each value to its first position (which only takes linear time), and then that `if y in lst[:j]:` becomes the constant-time `if first_positions[y] < j:`.

We could then take this memoization farther and cache the results of all sublists, so the inner loop only has to calculate each one the first time.

But, once you've done that, you can see what's actually happening (if not, add some `print`s in the middle) and come up with the cleverer algorithm that stores all the pair-sums up-front.

---

<sub>* The rule is vague enough that everyone on this page (including me) guessed wrong at what it meant. Thinking of all the ways it can be interpreted and looking over the expected output, I think I can figure out what they must have meant. But in a real-life specification, I would definitely ask them to clarify instead of guessing. And that's even more true for an interview, where getting you to ask for clarification may actually be the point.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

```
import itertools

final_=[]
for m in list(itertools.permutations(order,r=4)):
    if m[:2][0]==m[:2][1]:
        pass
    else:
        final_.append(tuple(sorted((sum(m[:2]),)+m[2:])))

print(set(final_))
```

output:

```
when order=(15, 8, 8, 3)
```

output:

```
{(3, 8, 23), (8, 8, 18), (8, 11, 15)}
```

when `order=(6, 5, 3, 8)`

output:

```
{(5, 8, 9), (3, 8, 11), (3, 5, 14), (6, 8, 8), (5, 6, 11), (3, 6, 13)}
```